# Loggin level is not loaded from property file

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, java.util.logging

I have set up a `java.util.logging.Logger` in my project as follows.

```
public static final String LOGGER_NAME = POSClient.class.getName();
public static Logger logger;

private static final String LOGGING_PROPERTY_FILE = "logging.properties";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Load logging properties.
    System.setProperty("java.util.logging.config.file", POSClient.class.getClassLoader().getResource(LOGGING_PROPERTY_FILE).getFile());

    // Initialise logger.
    logger = Logger.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME);
}
```

The following is my **logging.properties** file.

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.level = WARNING

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = WARNING

com.cineops.pos.level = WARNING
org.apache.http.level = FINEST
org.apache.http.wire.level = SEVERE
```

And when I try to log something out, the console always displays the message irrespective of the logging level. For example;

```
logger.log(Level.INFO, "Properties loaded successfully.");
```

will log the message onto the **Eclipse** console.

As you can see from the property file, I am trying to log **HttpClient** messages onto the console with no success. Is anything from from **Eclipse** blocking the settings from being loaded? Any help would be appreciated.

My **logging.properties** file is in the classpath (Resources folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try

```
File configFile = POSClient.class.getClassLoader().getResource(LOGGING_PROPERTY_FILE).getFile();
LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(configFile);
```

instead of

```
System.setProperty(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it and it is working (I used the `getResourceAsStream()` method instead). Also I have changed the way I use the logger object to `logger.info("Info Message")` from `logger.log(Level.INFO, "Info Message")` for convenience.